# Manually bootstrapping a component onto existing element

Tags: angular

Is it possible to manually bootstrap (insert and compile) an Angular2 component onto existing element and pass properties to it. I would like to do something like the following (described in React code):

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
});

var name = 'World!';

React.render(<Hello name={name} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

or is there some kind of a substitution for *$compile*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK There is no such functionality in angular2. But I think [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html) is what you are looking for (source code is [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/compiler/dynamic_component_loader.ts)).